# PFLoginViewController´s Twitter, Facebook buttons not working when subclassing

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

When I subclass PFLoginViewController from Parse so that I can customise UI, both Twitter and Facebook buttons stop working as they used to if I were not subclassing.
This is the class I instantiate my subclass from:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



// THIS DOES WORK (without subclassing)
//var loginVC: PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()

var loginVC:LogInViewController {
    get{
        let livc = LogInViewController()
        livc.delegate = self

        let suvc = SignUpViewController()
        suvc.delegate = self

        livc.signUpController? = suvc


        return livc
    }}
```

And this is my subclass of PFLogInViewController

```
class LogInViewController: PFLogInViewController {

static let forgotPassword = "Trouble Signing In?"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let lv = self.logInView

    self.facebookPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    self.fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, .Facebook, .Twitter, .SignUpButton, .LogInButton, .PasswordForgotten, .DismissButton]
    lv?.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))
    lv?.logo?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    lv?.emailAsUsername = true
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

It might be a bug in Parse´s side, though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You always can subscribe to button events but what I´m kind of reporting here is a bug, apparently.

Comment: this couple of lines will fix it as said before for those looking for a quick fix (add them up in viewDidLoad func of your PFLoginViewController subclass:)
`self.logInView?.facebookButton?.addTarget(self, action: "_loginWithFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.logInView?.twitterButton?.addTarget(self, action: "_loginWithTwitter", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue - it looks like this bug was patched in the GitHub repo (see [this commit](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/commit/d5d0c32742e95e9bdf27debbf49009930fde67f7)) but not in the Cocoapod, if that's what you're using.  I'm hoping they'll push the changes over soon :)

The reason for the bug in the old code is that the superclass is not updating the target/actions for the buttons when you set which fields you want in viewDidLoad.  PFLoginViewController configures the target/actions in *its* viewDidLoad, but since you're setting the self.fields *after* calling super.viewDidLoad (which is what you should be doing, since you always call super first :) ), the field target/actions aren't re-updated.  In other words, it looks like, the way PFLogInViewController was written, it only works if the fields don't change after its viewDidLoad is called :/.  And since the default fields don't include a Facebook button, the Facebook button will never be set up.  A simple solution is just to move self.fields =... before super.viewDidLoad().